# Is Kripke/relational/possible world semantics the special case of the the set semantics or first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, modal-logic, kripke-models

I am reading https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319225562 about expression of modal operators as the predicates in the first order (and possibly higher order) logic. My question is - is the modal logic the special case of first order logic (just some more axioms?) Is the Kripke/relational/possible world semantics the special case of the set semantics for the first order logic?

I have some doubts about this, because modal operator takse the formula/sentence as its arguments, but there is no structure (function or predicate) in the FOL, that could take formula/sentence as the argument, only connectives can act upon predicates/formulas but FOL connectives can not act as unary functions (like modal operators do).

Would be happy for clarification.

Comment: But higher order predicate can express all the content of modal operator, isn't so?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The OP isn't comparing propositional classical logic and propositional modal logic, but rather *first-order* classical logic and propositional modal logic. And propositional modal logic with the Kripke frame semantics is indeed a fragment of first-order classical logic in a natural way, per my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version:

### Yes, it is.

---

*Incidentally, [this old MSE answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2976579/28111) is related; it's not an exact duplicate, since there the OP is building off of this initial observation, but it covers some of the same ground. Also, [this old mathoverflow answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/a/120700/8133) while not directly related may be of separate interest.*

*Also, at some point I suspect you'll become unsatisfied with the level of detail available in introductory texts on the subject. For a more advanced text I strongly recommend [Chagrov/Zakharyaschev's awesome book](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/modal-logic-9780198537793?cc=us&lang=en&) - it's what I learned from.*

---

Kripke frames in the *propositional* modal logic context **are indeed** a special case of first-order logic in a natural way. This is a bit involved:

We start with the *languages*. Each propositional language $P=\{p_i:i\in I\}$ has a corresponding first-order language consisting of unary predicates, one for each propositional atom, together with a new binary relation $R$ - namely, $$\Sigma_P=\{R\}\cup\{U_i:i\in I\}.$$

Next, we pass from *Kripke frames* to *first-order structures*. Each frame/valuation pair $\mathcal{K}=((K,\rightarrow),\nu)$ for $P$ *(that is, $(K,\rightarrow)$ is a directed graph and $\nu$ is a map from $K\times P$ to $\{\top,\perp\}$)* has a corresponding $\Sigma_P$-structure $Struc_\mathcal{K}$ whose elements are worlds, whose unary predicates correspond to the sets of worlds where given propositional atoms hold, and whose binary relation corresponds to the accessibility relation. More precisely:

- The domain of $Struc_\mathcal{K}$ is $K$.
- The interpretation of $U_i$ in $Struc_\mathcal{K}$ is $\{w\in K: \nu(w, p_i)=\top\}$.
- The interpretation of $R$ in $Struc_\mathcal{K}$ is $\{(w,x)\in K^2: w\rightarrow x\}$.

**Note that every $\Sigma_P$-structure is of the form $Struc_\mathcal{K}$ for some $\mathcal{K}$**.

Now we come to the payoff. We have a translation $$\varphi\mapsto\hat{\varphi}$$ from propositional modal sentences in $P$ to first-order formulas with one free variable in $\Sigma_P$ such that for each frame/valuation pair $\mathcal{K}=((K,\rightarrow), \nu)$ and world $w\in K$ we have $$w\models_\mathcal{K}\varphi\quad\iff\quad Struc_\mathcal{K}\models\hat{\varphi}(w).$$

This translation is a bit tedious to write down in full detail, but here's an example which should illustrate how it works: in the language $P=\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$, taking our modal sentence to be $$\varphi:\quad p_1\vee(\Box (p_2\wedge\neg p_3)\wedge\Diamond p_1)$$ we would have $$\hat{\varphi}(x):\quad [U_1(x)]\vee[\forall y(xRy\implies U_2(y)\wedge \neg U_3(y))\wedge\exists y(xRy\wedge U_1(y))].$$ *(I've added some unnecessary parentheses, and used both square and round brackets, for clarity.)* Note that at each "stage" in our translation we have a "current world," and the accessibility relation $R$ comes in when we interpret the modalities as quantifiers: if we're "currently at $x$" then "$\Box \psi$" and "$\Diamond\psi$" correspond to "$\forall y(xRy\implies \hat{\psi})$" and "$\exists y(xRy\wedge \hat{\psi})$" respectively.

- It's worth noting that the above yields a purely syntactic fact: since $K$ is sound and complete for Kripke frames, the above tells us that for all propositional modal $\gamma,\varphi$ we have $$\gamma\vdash_K\varphi\quad\iff\quad \hat{\gamma}\vdash\hat{\varphi}$$ where "$\vdash_K$" is provability in system $K$ and "$\vdash$" is the usual notion of provability in first-order logic. Many properties of frames are appropriately first-order expressible and yield further equivalences: e.g. $$\gamma\vdash_{S_5}\varphi\quad\iff\quad \hat{\gamma}\wedge \theta\vdash\hat{\varphi}$$ where "$\theta$" is the sentence asserting that $R$ is reflexive, transitive, and symmetric.

**So in a precise sense we have a correspondence between Kripke semantics and a fragment of first-order logic**.

That said, this does not mean that classical first-order logic is "better" than propositional modal logic: there is an important tradeoff between power and tameness, and sometimes - especially in applications, e.g. in computer science - we care a lot about how tame we can make things while still having a bare minimum of expressive power. The study of tame fragments of first-order logic is extremely deep and interesting.

---

Now let me mention some subtleties of the analysis above.

One immediate question is how large a fragment of first-order logic is given by Kripke semantics via the above translation. Certainly there's a restriction on the language - we only ever get structures in a single binary relation and a bunch of unary relations. However, it turns out that the situation is even worse: there are first-order formulas in such a language which don't come from Kripke frames at all. For example, consider the very boring propositional language $\{p_1\}$. The formula $$\varphi(x):\quad\exists y(x\not=y\wedge U_1(y))$$ is true of an element $w$ in $Struc_\mathcal{K}$ iff in $\mathcal{K}$ there is some world other than $w$ where $p_1$ is true. But this is not modally expressible - intuitively, starting at a world $w$ we can only every survey worlds a bounded distance from $w$. So Kripke semantics gives us a proper sub-fragment of first-order logic *even after* we make the obvious language restriction. Indeed, there are lots of "tameness" results about modal logic which show that the gap between "modal-induced" $\Sigma_P$-formulas and arbitrary first-order $\Sigma_P$-formulas is extremely vast.

On the other hand, when we broaden our horizons a bit there *are* some things modal logic can do which first-order logic can't. Consider for example [**Lob's axiom**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provability_logic) $$\Box(\Box p\rightarrow p)\rightarrow \Box p.$$ This is validated in a frame $(K,\rightarrow)$ - that is, true at every world under every valuation - iff $(K,\rightarrow)$ is *converse well-founded*. But this is not a first-order expressible property. Indeed, the complexity of validity in this sense is [quite high](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/malq.19750210114).

Finally, we might ask about *non*-Kripkean semantics. Here my lack of experience shows, but to the best of my knowledge nothing really changes: **all natural propositional modal logics** *(as far as I know)* **are appropriately embeddable in first-order logic**.